# Objective-C file writing process become slower and slower as more files to be produced

Tags: objective-c, encryption, file-io, zip

This is the main part of my ObjC epub files encryptor code

```
@autoreleasepool {
    for(NSMutableString* epub in self.epubs){
        bookKey = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self genRandStringLength:16]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(encrypt:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:epub,bookKey,nil] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

The selector "encrypt" includes these method calls

- create folder for epub extraction
- unzip epub file and put the content files into extraction folder
- create ZipFile for encrypted epub
- read each files within extraction folder, create ZipWriteStream and encrypt the file data
- write each encrypted data stream into ZipFile
- close ZipFile and change zip name extension to .epub

The process is quiet fast when it is just started. But the process getting slower and slower as more file had been written. i'm so sorry for i cannot expose the selector's definition because of my company secrecy policy. but i'm very sure the problem isn't come from it. Below is the console log sample. actually those files are just the clone of the same file with different name

- Epub Name : A.epub

  - Book Key : 4151FDD721564E40
  - Time taken : 0.440156
- Epub Name : B.epub

  - Book Key : BC23C09C4625429E
  - Time taken : 0.675541
- Epub Name : C.epub

  - Book Key : AF872798FAEA4EDE
  - Time taken : 0.974213
- Epub Name : D.epub

  - Book Key : 250C319928E54D2C
  - Time taken : 1.332154
- Epub Name : E.epub

  - Book Key : EC4EC65605D246EB
  - Time taken : 1.705329
- Epub Name : F.epub

  - Book Key : E10588A8CB584ACD
  - Time taken : 2.209807
- Epub Name : G.epub

  - Book Key : 9B572BF9428E4DFB
  - Time taken : 2.797980
- Epub Name : H.epub

  - Book Key : BC05B2A629C44A85
  - Time taken : 3.389614
- Epub Name : I.epub

  - Book Key : 79DB7AAFC8CA4655
  - Time taken : 4.936718
- Epub Name : J.epub

  - Book Key : B0413DF2356048A7
  - Time taken : 5.441939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should profile your program with the Time Profile tool in Instruments, and see what's taking the time. Also, an inner autorelease pool for that loop might be helpful if memory growth turns out to be an issue.

(For future reference, "I'm quite sure it's not X" nearly always ends up meaning "It's X" ;) )

Comment: thanx for the advice. anyway did u mean that autoreleasepool do nothing before the end of that for loop?

Comment: Indeed. Your autorelease pool won't release any objects in it until after the entire loop is over, just as the nesting would imply.

Comment: thank you. how about the code inside called functions. do i have to put separate autoreleases for each of them

Comment: autorelease pools are organized in per-thread stacks. If you measure significant amounts of transient object allocation in a function (measure not guess!), then putting a pool around it to clean up might help.

Comment: ok thanx. but let say if i solve this autorelease issue entirely, do you think this will also solve my problem above? because i think i had experience this problem before on java

Comment: I don't think you will be able to solve your problem without measuring using the tools. Guessing is a bad way to solve problems.

Comment: i guess you didn't experienced this kind of problem before. anyway thanx for all of your answers and advices. be free to put it here if you find the solution :-)

Comment: Heh. Performance optimization of Cocoa code is actually my specialty, and has been for many years. Optimizing without using the tools is a waste of time, and you may as well learn to use them now rather later. If you don't actually want to solve your problem, feel free to ignore that advice though.